# How to prove $\det(tI-BA^T)=\det(tI-B^TA)t^{m-n}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $A,B\in M_{m \times n}$. Show that $\det(tI-BA^T)=\det(tI-B^TA)t^{m-n}$

I want to solve this question and I have an idea probably useful which is from [Sylvester's determinant identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17831/sylvesters-determinant-identity?noredirect=1&lq=1). If I can find some matrices such that $$P^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}I&\\&\ BA^T\end{bmatrix}P=\begin{bmatrix}I&\\&\ A^TB\end{bmatrix}$$, then two matrices are similar and have the same characteristic polynomial. Hope someone can give me a hint how to construct these four matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Use these two facts:

$1.$ $\det(tI - BA^T) = \det(tI - AB^T)$ since for any $C$, $\det(C) = \det(C^T)$

$2.$ The algebraic multiplicity of the non-zero eigenvalues of $AB^T$ and $B^TA$ are the same (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332674/do-the-non-zero-eigenvalues-of-ab-and-ba-have-the-same-algebraic-multiplicity-f).)

Comment: Thanks! I know how to prove it.